# how to use year function and groupby to do a dynamic search?

Tags: sql

1. Run a query that returns the number of trouble tickets in the VTM024… table, but only the ones created in the year 2015. Note: when setting the where criteria, use a function to extract the Year portion from the timestamp field.
2. Using the Year function in the first answer, write SQL that shows the number of trouble tickets created in each year dynamically, and do this using a “GROUP BY” clause in the SQL. It should return something like:

```
2012       10
2013       54
2014       111
etc
```

I was able to answer first question myself:

```
SELECT COUNT(CREATE_TIME) FROM TRACS_DW1.VTM024TROUBLE_TKT 
WHERE EXTRACT (YEAR FROM CREATE_TIME) = 2015
```

I need help with 2nd question. I cant get groupby and extract functions together.

i have added a picture of my table.
[image]

Comment: Please do not tag spam irrelevant products.  Only tag the products you're *actually* using.

Comment: Also, including what you tried but didn't work would help.

Answer (score 0):

Add EXTRACT (YEAR FROM CREATE_TIME) as year to your select query and group by the year field.

Comment: SELECT EXTRACT (YEAR FROM CREATE_TIME) AS THEYEAR, COUNT(*)
    FROM TRACS_DW1.VTM024TROUBLE_TKT
    GROUP BY EXTRACT (YEAR FROM CREATE_TIME)

Comment: now, I would like to add Month as well, i will have to use exract again. but the syntax isnt corrrect

Comment: i GOT IT

SELECT EXTRACT (YEAR FROM CREATE_TIME) AS THEYEAR, 
EXTRACT (MONTH FROM CREATE_TIME) AS MONTH, COUNT(*)
    FROM TRACS_DW1.VTM024TROUBLE_TKT
    GROUP BY EXTRACT (YEAR FROM CREATE_TIME), EXTRACT (MONTH FROM CREATE_TIME)
    ORDER BY THEYEAR;